# Is there a term for "leaderboard" or "scorebased" competitive multiplayer?

Tags: terminology, competitive-gaming

I'm attempting to research competitive games of a specific type, where the players aren't ever in "direct" competition with each other, and having difficulty describing them.  General examples include racing games, where players individually try to get the best time on a track, classic arcade games, where players attempt to obtain the highest score, or, for a more recent example, the "daily challenge" announced recently for the PC version of Spelunky, found here: http://spelunkyworld.com/dailychallenge/‎

The key aspect is that (for lack of a better word) the games are completely asynchronous: Player A's playthrough never has a direct effect on Player B, and vice-versa. "Asynchronous" isn't a good enough term, though, because certain turn-based board and strategy games (such as Scrabble and Chess) can be played asynchronously, but they don't fit the criteria: they are directly competitive in that Player A's turn directly affects how Player B will respond or play. In the types of games that fit the word I'm looking for, a player's performance is unaffected by all and any of the other players competing.

Is there a word or phrase to describe this type of competition?

Comment: I know exactly what kind of game you're talking about and I'm also at a loss for a specific word to describe it.  +1

Comment: Exactly so. We don't close questions based on what their answers are. That's silly and circular. And this is *still* not a recommendation question, and there is no other ban policy that applies to it. By all means vote to close, but please find a valid reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no commonly accepted phrase or word that means specifically this type of "non-interacting competitive multiplayer."

However, the alternative, in which the players **do** directly interact, is commonly described as **head-to-head**.

Answer (score 2):

*Challenge-based*? That seems to fit what you are describing. The challenge could be to beat a high score or lap time or just about anything. Games like *Forza* have options to challenge a friend to beat your time on a specific track, which is competitive but not interactive.

Comment: As an aside, I've just realised that playing *Football Manager* online is a bit like this.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no interaction at all, you might be able to describe it as a competitive singleplayer game.

Alternatively, you noted that the class of game has the slightly-less-common feature of not being directly competitive. You could describe such games as *indirectly* competitive, if you're feeling particularly literal.

If those don't work, you could make the analogy to an arcade or flash game.